# Creating new directories

Tags: java, file-io

I'm stuck with the fact that no folder is made.

```
private static File createNewTempDir() {
File baseDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
String baseNamePrefix = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_" + Math.random() + "-";
LOG.info(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
File tempDir = new File(baseDir, baseNamePrefix + "0");
LOG.info(tempDir.getAbsolutePath());

tempDir.mkdirs();

if (tempDir.exists()) {
  LOG.info("I would be happy!");
}
else {
  LOG.info("No folder there");
}
return tempDir;
}
```

Is there any wrong with it? I can get the LOG that no folders are there...

Comment: are you sure the folder isn't there? you log it's not there only when it exists.

Comment: It would seem the problem is the negation in `if (!tempDir.exists())`. That would print "I would be happy!" if the path does NOT exist, and "No folder there" if it DOES.

Comment: What has this question to do with ant? I cannot see any usage of it. Maybe you should remove the tag.

Comment: Sorry joergl, Dave Newton, Andreas Baus - I edited. The '!' was my mistype. And the tag is wrong.. But the problem still goes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, but your conditional is wrong:

```
if (tempDir.exists()) {
  LOG.info("I would be happy!");
}
else {
  LOG.info("No folder there");
}
```

The folder is created indeed, you can check that by getting the path and opening on Explorer.

**EDIT**: It works on Windows at least. I cleaned it up a bit:

```
   public static void main() {
        File baseDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File tempDir = new File(baseDir, "test0");
        System.err.println(tempDir.getAbsolutePath());

        tempDir.mkdir();

        System.err.println("is it a dir? " + tempDir.isDirectory());
        System.err.println("does it exist? " + tempDir.exists());
    }
```

Output:

> C:\Users\marsch1\AppData\Local\Temp\test0 
>   is it a dir? true 
>   does it exist? true

Comment: Thx Marcelo. I don't know why this problem occured. It's a fact that if I follow your code then I can verify that the folder is made. But if I follow my code, it doesn't work. Anyway, thx for help. I'll check the problem after, but now the solution is needed more... Anyway thanks for help

Comment: Rude-Student, I just realized I used `file.mkdir()` instead of `file.mkdirS()`. Maybe that`s your problem?

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for the interest